# How automatically refresh a div upon a successful ajax execution

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to refresh the div that contains a table that show the data after a successful insertion of new data using ajax.

Here's my code:

```
            $("span.save").live('click', function() { 

                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var name = $('.ingr_name_' +id).val();
                var amount = $('.amt_' +id).val();
                var unit = $('.unit_' +id).val();

                if(name.length > 0 && amount.length > 0 && unit.length > 0)
                {   
                    var dataString = "id=<?php echo $this->uri->segment(3); ?>&name=" +name +"&amount=" +amount +"&unit=" +unit;

                    //alert(dataString);

                    $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>recipe/add_ingr",
                       data: dataString,
                       success: function(){                         
                           //I wanted to refresh the div here. Where the div's id="ingredients_list"

                           alert('Recipe ingredient added.')
                       },
                       error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(error)
                       }
                    });

                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Please fill out all fields.");   
                }

            });
```

I've been searching how to do the div refresh but they don't fit my needs for this problem. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: BTW I'd be super careful `eval`ing PHP that comes from the front end. Essentially, nothing stops me from noticing that you do it and passing along a query for the users table. Unless, of course, you're not connecting to the database, but then why would you need PHP?

Comment: @Josh, I'd assume this is a PHP file and those PHP segments are being evaluated by the engine on page request... Where is eval being used?

Comment: @PlagueEditor Ah, I see that now. I guess I just get the willies everytime I see the two mixed together.

Comment: Is there a way for me to be able to do what I wanted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `success` handler of the ajax call you will get a response in the first argument. Using that you can create the desired markup and then append it into `ingredients_list` element.

```
success: function(response){
    //Using response object create the desired markup for recipe table 

    $("#ingredients_list").html("markUpCreatedUsingResponseFromServer");
    alert('Recipe ingredient added.')
 }
```

Comment: `response` will contain whatever `url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>recipe/add_ingr"` returns as a response

Comment: I see. But is there a way that I can just do some call like the location.reload() in javascript? Coz I wanted to show the newly inserted ingredient so that it could have the edit function coz if i would just append the markup, i would not be able to have the edit capability.